# Emacs won't open file in Bazaar repository

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, bazaar

I have a [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) installation, and am trying to open `/Bugzilla/Install/CPAN.pm` using [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). However, I get this error when attempting to do so:

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory, bzr
```

Why do I get that message? Why won't `emacs` load the file? How do I fix this problem?

EDITS:

I am trying to open it with the command `emacs Bugzilla/Install/CPAN.pm` while in the `bugzilla` directory.

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you opening the file? Are you just running `emacs /Bugzilla/Install/CPAN.pm`?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly how I am trying to open it.

EDIT: Actually, I am not using the first `/` as I am inside the `bugzilla` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this error has nothing to do with Perl.  `bzr` is the command-line client for the [Bazaar distributed version control system](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/).  Apparently, your Bugzilla installation is inside a Bazaar repository.  Emacs is detecting this automatically, and trying to activate its version control mode, but you don't have the `bzr` client installed.  Emacs isn't prepared for that situation.  It actually did load the file you requested; it just didn't switch to that buffer automatically.  (And you'll probably get more errors if you try to edit the buffer.)

You can install the `bzr` package, or find the `.bzr` directory and rename it so Emacs won't detect it, or customize the `vc-handled-backends` variable in Emacs to remove `Bzr` from the list.